# Finding Text between different Xml Elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document that I am attempting to parse through using C#.  Within this document I have the following as an example:

```
<text>
   <body>
       <pb facs="somestring" />
       <opener>
          <address />
       </opener>
       <p>some text - might be anything
       <pb facs="someotherstring" />
       more text or possibly xml. </p>
   </body>
</text>
```

Each of the "pb" tags indicates a page break in the text.  So I basically need to loop through this text, and every time I hit a "pb" tag, I need to create a new page and any text or xml that follows that "pb" tag is part of that new page until I hit the next "pb" tag (in which the former process repeats).  Normally I would simply do a .SelectNodes() with some XQuery to get everything of that type. The problem here is that the "pb" tag doesn't WRAP the text which follows it; it is always a closed tag (meaning it never has any child elements). So I can't just get all the child elements of the "pb" tag because there are none.  I need to get all the siblings (as well as any free form text) that exists BETWEEN a "pb" tag and it's next "pb" tag (or in the case of the last "pb" tag, that tag and the closing "body" tag).  I'm completely at a loss as to how to even start. Where the real challenge comes into play is that each "pb" tag may not be a direct sibling.  Sometimes, a "pb" might exist inside another element (such as a "p" tag, thus making it "nephew" for lack of a better term of another "pb" tag") or it might be a direct sibling.

And just to note, this is is utilising a standardised text encoding (called TEI) so I can't just make the decision to wrap the "pb" tag around the elements that make up the page; that's non-compliant with the standard.

**UPDATE**
I've tried implementing @Tomalak's solution and I've gotten a little closer but still not there yet.  To save time I've copied my code and a sample of the actual file I'm currently testing with to help illustrate the issue.

While the code fires without exception, it actually doesn't give me the content between the two "pb" tags. I end up with a NodeList where the first entry is empty and the second entry contains ALL of the xml / text in the "body" tag (rather than just the text / xml between the first "pb" tag and the second "pb" tag). Hoping someone can shed some light on this.  Code below.

**C# Code**

```
var pages = text.SelectNodes ("//tei:pb", _xmlns);
StringBuilder pageText = new StringBuilder ();
//Letters.Domain.Objects.FileInfo file = null;

for (int i=0; i < pages.Count; i++) {
    pageCount++;
    XmlNode page = pages [i];
    //string pageNumber = this.GetAttributeValue ("n", page);
    string facsId = this.GetAttributeValue ("facs", page).Substring(1);

    //get the text between page breaks
    var path = "//node()[not(self::tei:pb) and ancestor::tei:text/tei:body and count(preceding::tei:pb) = " + i + "]";
    var pbText = pages [i].SelectNodes (path, _xmlns);

    //Do something with the content of pbText
}
```

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?oxygen RNGSchema="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="xml"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<teiHeader xml:id="L1916_2004">
    <!--header stuff goes here-->
</teiHeader>

<facsimile> 
    <graphic xml:id="L1916_2004_img_1" url="1e84e52835597bd4d2229709a02f0a93.jpg"/> 
    <graphic xml:id="L1916_2004_img_2" url="b6ad122b71088b7eec53262038ffa443.jpg"/> 
</facsimile>               
<text type="letter"><!-- issue to resolve with a previous process? -->
    <body>
        <pb n="5008" facs="#L1916_2004_img_1"/>
            <opener>
                <address><addrLine>Zossen</addrLine></address>
                <dateline><date>Xmas Day 1915</date></dateline>
                <salute>Dear old pet,</salute> 
            </opener> 
        <p>No letter from you yet. I am so <lb/> lonely today - you remember last year <lb/> in 8 Hartstonge St. with the little ones running <lb/> wild &#x2014; why do you grip me so much <lb/> &amp; why are my thoughts so cluttered around <lb/> you? Mollie write me, I do so want your <lb/> sympathy, my work is so hard, and difficulties <lb/> so many - but of course if I had you here to <lb/> tell all my worries to, things would run <lb/> smoothly - I trust you and all at home
           <pb n="5009" facs="#L1916_2004_img_2"/>
           are enjoying yourselves, even now as I write <lb/> this letter &#x2014;</p>
       <p>I cant write more now, fondest love <lb/> Kiss them all for me </p>
       <closer>
          <salute> Yours ever </salute>
          <signed><unclear>Cara</unclear></signed>
       </closer>  
     </body>
   </text>
</TEI>
```

Comment: You're parsing HTML not XML. XML Parsers won't like the HTML, I'd look at the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It's not HTML.  It's TEI which is an XML based standard for encoding literary text.

Comment: I stand corrected! Please forgive my presumption and inattention, best of luck :)

Comment: Looks like you've abandoned your question. This is not a nice thing to do. Please either comment on the answers if your question has not been solved - or vote on and pick one of the answers if your question has been solved.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay on the response.  I only work a couple days a week on this project and I got pulled off this to work on something else.  *sigh* if only the powers that be let me work on things I like instead of the stuff they want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
var breaks = doc.SelectNodes("//pb"); 

for (var i = 0; i < breaks.Count; i++) {
    var path = "../node()[count(preceding-sibling::pb) = " + (i + 1) + "]";
    var contents = breaks[i].SelectNodes(path);

    // so something with contents
}
```

This assumes that all `<pb>` nodes in your document are A) siblings that B) occur on the root level of the content, i.e. like your sample XML indicates.

---

(Edit, after the question was updated): A solution that does not make such an assumption would work with the `preceding` axis, instead of `preceding-sibling`:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

var nsman = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsman.AddNamespace("tei", "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0");

var breaks = doc.SelectNodes("//tei:pb", nsman); 

for (var i = 0; i < breaks.Count; i++) {
    var path = String.Format(@"
        //node()[
            ancestor::tei:body
            and not(self::tei:pb)
            and count(preceding::tei:pb) = {0}
        ]
    ", i + 1);

    var contents = breaks[i].SelectNodes(path, nsman);

    // so something with contents
}
```

Note that for `i == 1` this will return the `<p>` of which the responsible `<pb>` is a child of. This `<p>` will naturally contain a bit of the following page. The initial text node before the `<pb>` will be returned *as well* (separately), but here you will have no immediate indication that it was taken from inside a `<p>`. Pick your poison.

Play around with the expression. You might want to try adding `not(.//pb)` to exclude the elements containing `<pb>` and go for their contents only.

Comment: That won't work because the "pb" tag isn't always a sibling of the others (something I didn't realise until you posted your answer). I will amend my question to reflect this.

Comment: @ShaneMcGarry I can still only see sibling <pb> nodes in your sample.

Comment: Sorry @Tomalak - I updated the description but failed to update the sample.  I've updated the sample to reflect what I was discussing.

Comment: @ShaneMcGarry So, what happens in the case of the `<pb>` that is a child of `<p>`? Also, are you only interested in extracting the plain text nodes or are the other nodes like `<opener>` of significance as well?

Comment: Yeah, I'm interested in extracting everything, not just the plain text nodes.  If you think of the XML as the encoded representation of a physical letter or a book, the <pb> indicates a page break.  The <p> (like in HTML) indicates a paragraph.  Paragraphs can span two pages so that's why a <pb> could exist as a child element of a <p>.  I use the <pb> to know when I need to start a new page (it has some additional attributes that give me other information as well) so I need to extract all the content that exists between two <pb> tags so I can get the "content" of the page.

Comment: @Shane See modified answer.

Comment: Hi Tomalak - I just updated the OP with some further information.  I'm still not having much luck.  Using what you provided, I'm actually getting all of the contents of the <text> block instead of just individual sections between <pb>.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Shane Sorry for the late response, I have dug up that thread from my todo list only a few minutes ago. See modified answer, the spirit is still the same, but it works against your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the XML into an XDocument object, say X.

Then call X.Root.Value.